# iOS UIWebView shown just part of content in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I would like to have `UIImage` and `UIWebView` in `UIScrollView` so when I scroll first it would disappear image and then I would scroll with just webView. So I set it in storyboard and I added these methods to my code:

```
- (void)setScrollViewContentSize
{
    float sizeOfContent = 0;
    UIView *lLast = [_scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
    NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;

    sizeOfContent = wd+ht;

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [webView sizeToFit];
    [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height)];
    [self setScrollViewContentSize];
}
```

It's working just with one problem. When I scroll for a few lines I get new content of webView but after that I don't see anything. I think it has something to do with cache and that I am not scrolling in webView but with scrollView and so webView doesn't know that it should display that content. Anyone could help? Thanks

Comment: You can add the `image` in the `webcontent` directly on the top in html and load the html, it will do that same thing I guess?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could but I am loading image via Rest API and from Base64 so I could it could be more complicated but if there isn't easy solution for my problem maybe it's better solution.

Comment: Is your image big in size? If not, just wait till the image has downloaded, download to a location and add an extra `div` in your html with `img` tag with the reference of the image file location. it will solve your problem, and I think its the easiest one.